# How to select objects in the outliner with only hotkeys

Tags: outliner

Hopefully this is a super easy answer for someone. Just curious if anyone knows how to use the keyboard to make an object selection from the outliner? I mainly need this because I have a ton of objects that I need to name and doing this with arrow keys, a hotkey for object select, and then using F2 to rename would be so much more efficient than having to click on each one with my mouse.

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In outliner you can use 'A' key to select all objects. 
With one object selected press 'shift' and select another object for range select.
Use 'B' key to box select.
Besides use Batch rename instead of single Rename!

Answer (score 1):

I use "industry standard" interaction mode in Blender 2.92

With the Outliner focused, F2 works to rename the object under the mouse cursor.  Ctrl + F2 will batch rename multiple selected objects.
This solves your problem.

Be advised:  When Outliner is focused, you can navigate by keyboard and select different objects with arrow keys, however F2 will always rename the object under the mouse cursor, not the object selected.  (This is infuriating behaviour, and if anyone knows how to change it please let me know!)